# How to stop cleanly stop code from executing after res.send()

Tags: javascript, node.js

On one of my api endpoints I've got a middleware function that checks whether the session is still valid (verifySession). That function calls another function (validateObjectId) that checks whether the passed-in (mongodb) Id is a valid ObjectId. I would like to be able to exit verifySession() if validateObjectId() detects an invalid Id.

However, the console.log and the rest of the code that runs in a normal scenario, where the Id is valid, still runs and obviously complains that the HTTP response has ended and can't add to it.

What am I doing wrong?

```
// EDIT 1 BEGIN
/**
 * 
 * @param {mongoose.Types.ObjectId} objectId Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer.
 * @returns A rejected Promise if the value passed is not a valid MongoDB ObjectId.
 */
const validateObjectId = async (objectId) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Check if the passed-in id is a valid MongoDB ObjectId. Return with an error of it's not.
    if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(objectId)) {
      reject({
        error: ERROR_MESSAGES.INVALID_OBJECTID,
        errorCode: ERROR_CODES.INVALID_OBJECTID
      });
    }
    resolve(objectId);
  })
}

// EDIT 1 END


// Verify Refresh Token Middleware (which will be verifying the session)
let verifySession = async (req, res, next) => {
  // Grab the refresh token from the request header.
  let refreshToken = req.header('x-refresh-token');

  // Grab the _id from the request header.
  let _id = req.header('_id');

  console.log('ObjectId: ', _id);

  await validateObjectId(_id)
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('GOT HEREEEEEEEEEEEEEE', err);
      // return res.send(err);
      return res.status(STATUS_CODES.UNAUTHORIZED).send(err);
    });

    console.log('GOT HERE BUT SHOULD NOT HAVE');
  // Verify the session.
}
```

I've tried adding and removing the 'return' keyword.

I know that I could put the rest of the functionality in the .then() of the validateObjectId(), but I consider that affects the readability of the code.

If I have a clause at the top of the function that could end the whole function, I'd like to keep  it there as well as the part that ends that function (the .catch() block).

Comment: You seem to have forgotten that you have a function inside a function. The `return` keyword returns form the function `(err) => {...` not the function `verifySession`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `return` in a callback function (like the one you have in `catch()`) only ends the execution of *that* function. When that `return` executes, the promise that was returned by `catch()` resolves, and so the `await` operator now resumes the function it is in (which is `verifySession` and not the callback function).

You can solve this in many ways. For instance, moving the success path inside a `then` callback:

```
  await validateObjectId(_id)
    .then(() = {
      console.log('GET HERE ONLY WHEN NO ERROR');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('GOT HEREEEEEEEEEEEEEE', err);
      return res.status(STATUS_CODES.UNAUTHORIZED).send(err);
    });
```

Or using `try ... catch`:

```
  try {
      await validateObjectId(_id)
      console.log('GET HERE ONLY WHEN NO ERROR');
  } catch(err) {
      console.log('GOT HEREEEEEEEEEEEEEE', err);
      return res.status(STATUS_CODES.UNAUTHORIZED).send(err);
  }
```

The same, but moving the success path after the `try` block:

```
  try {
      await validateObjectId(_id)
  } catch(err) {
      console.log('GOT HEREEEEEEEEEEEEEE', err);
      return res.status(STATUS_CODES.UNAUTHORIZED).send(err);
  }
  console.log('GET HERE ONLY WHEN NO ERROR');
```

Note that in these `try/catch` versions, the `return` applies to the `verifySession` function, not to some callback.

Comment: thank you for the reply, but I feel you have not read the very last part of the post. I have specified that I know I could put everything in the .then() for the validateObjectId(), but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: That's why I have offered a second option?

Comment: Added one more... let me know what you don't like.

Comment: Ok, @trincot, so the first `try ... catch` is very similar to the `.then()` which is what I was trying to avoid.

The second one, however, does do what I was looking for! Thank you very much. 

Would you be able to shed some knowledge on why the second `try ... catch` works, but my option doesn't? I find them quite similar.

Comment: Added a paragraph at the start of my answer.

Comment: Much appreciated. I've marked your answer as the answer. If you think this kind of question is something that someone else might have, an upvote can give it a better chance of it being seen by others in need.